# set variables in batch to text file values

Tags: text, batch-file

I have a text file which is made up of a new value on each line. The amount of lines will vary (expand over time).

I would like to set a variable in a batch file for each of those values. Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to read from each line of the file into separate variable then use this. It can also be configured into a loop if you want it to get all the lines instead of just specific lines that way you wouldn't have to put 100 commands for 100 lines.

```
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (TEXTFILEPATH.txt) do (
set /a N+=1
set v[!N!]=%%a
)
set line1=%v[1]%
set line2=%v[2]%
set line3=%v[3]%
set line4=%v[4]%

echo %line1%
echo %line2%
echo %line3%
echo %line4%

endlocal
```

Make sure the `endlocal` is **after** the use of the variables.

If you want to write to specific lines in the text file, here is a post for that.

[Write batch variable into specific line in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686261/write-batch-variable-into-specific-line-in-a-text-file/10702194#10702194)

Comment: I suggest you to use the array notation for these variables: `set v[!N!]=%%a`, it is a clearer and standard form that everybody recognizes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990

Comment: I guess using the array notation would be easier to understand. I've never used it before until now I've always used the above code. I updated my code.