# Batch File - Insert Line into file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to insert a line into a file using the following code (from [Write batch variable into specific line in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686261/write-batch-variable-into-specific-line-in-a-text-file))

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set inputfile=variables.txt

set tempfile=%random%-%random%.tmp

copy /y nul %tempfile%

set line=0

for /f "delims=" %%l in (%inputfile%) do (
   set /a line+=1
   if !line!==4 (
       echo WORDS YOU REPLACE IT WITH>>%tempfile%
   ) else (
    echo %%l>>%tempfile%
)
)

del %inputfile%
ren %tempfile% %inputfile%

endlocal
```

My problem is the file has comment lines (which start with semicolons) which need to be kept

```
; directory during network startup. This statement must indicate a local disc
; drive on your PC and not a network disc drive.
LOCALDRIVE=C:\TEMP;

; PANELISATION PART/NET NAMING CONVENTION
; When jobs are panelised, parts/nets are renamed for each panel step by
```

When I run the batch file, it ignores the semicolon lines, So I only get:

```
LOCALDRIVE=C:\TEMP;
```

What do I need to do to keep the semicolon lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `FOR` command treats `;` as the end-of-line character, so all those lines that start with `;` are being ignored.

Add `eol=` to your `FOR` command, like this:

```
for /f "eol= delims=" %%l in (%inputfile%) do (
```

Comment: No, that will set the EOL character to a space. It will work with the example file, but may not work in all cases.

Comment: @dbenham You are right, this will work for the example file, but may not work in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

The EOL option determines what lines are to be ignored. The default value is a semicolon. If you know a character that can never appear in the first position of a line, then you can simply set EOL to that character. For example, if you know a line can't start with `|`, then you could use

```
for /f "eol=| delims=" %%l in (%inputfile%) do ...
```

There is an awkward syntax that disables EOL completely, and also disables DELIMS:

```
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%l in (%inputfil%) do ...
```

Note that FOR /F always discards empty lines, so either of the above would result in:

```
; directory during network startup. This statement must indicate a local disc
; drive on your PC and not a network disc drive.
LOCALDRIVE=C:\TEMP;
; PANELISATION PART/NET NAMING CONVENTION
; When jobs are panelised, parts/nets are renamed for each panel step by
```

A trick is used if you want to preserve empty lines. Use FIND or FINDSTR to insert the line number before each line, and then use expansion find/replace to remove the line number. Now you know the line never begins with `;`, so you can ignore the EOL option.

```
for /f "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /n "^" "%inputfile%"') do (
  set "ln=%%L"
  set "ln=!ln:*:=!"
  REM You now have the original line, do whatever needs to be done here
)
```

But all of the above have a potential problem in that you have delayed expansion enabled when you expand the FOR variable, which means that any content containing `!` will be corrupted. To solve this you must toggle delayed expansion on and off within the loop:

```
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
...
for /f "delims=" %%L in (findstr /n "^" "%inputfile%") do (
  set "ln=%%L"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "ln=!ln:*:=!"
  REM You now have the original line with ! preserved, do whatever needs done here
  endlocal
)
```

Also, when ECHOing an empty line, it will print out `ECHO is off` unless you do something like

```
echo(!ln!
```

It takes time to open and position the write cursor to the end every time you use `>>` within the loop. It is faster to enclose the entire operation in one set of parentheses and redirect once. Also, you can replace the DEL and REN with a single MOVE command.

Here is a final robust script:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "inputfile=variables.txt"
set line=0
>"%inputfile%.new" (
  for /f "delims=" %%L in (findstr /n "^" "%inputfile%") do (
    set "txt=%%L"
    set /a line+=1
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "txt=!txt:*:=!"
    if !line! equ 4 (
      echo New line content here
    ) else (
      echo(!txt!
    )
    endlocal
  )
)
move /y "%inputfile%.new" "%inputfile%" >nul
endlocal
```

That is an awful lot of work for such a simple task, and it requires a lot of arcane knowledge.

There is a much quicker hack that works as long as

- your first 4 lines do not exceed 1021 bytes
- none of your first 3 lines have trailing control characters that need to be preserved
- the remaining lines do not have `<tab>` characters that must be preserved (MORE converts `<tab>` into a string of spaces.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "inputfile=variables.txt"
>"%inputfile%.new" (
  <"%inputfile%" (
    for /l %%N in (1 1 3) do (
      set "ln="
      set /p "ln="
      echo(!ln!
    )
  )
  echo New line content here
  more +4 "%inputfile%"
)
move /y "%inputfile%.new" "%inputfile%"
```

That is still a lot of work and arcane knowledge.

**I would use my JREPL.BAT utility**

Batch is really a terrible tool for text processing. That is why I developed [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) to manipulate text using regular expressions. It is a hybrid JScript/batch script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. It is extremely versatile, robust, and fast.

A minimal amount of code is required to solve your problem with JREPL. Your problem doesn't really require the regular expression capabilities.

```
jrepl "^" "" /jendln "if (ln==4) $txt='New content here'" /f "variables.txt" /o -
```

If used within a batch script, then you must use `call jrepl ...` because JREPL.BAT is also a batch script.

Comment: EDIT - Fixed the code that toggles delayed expansion ON and OFF - the counter must be incremented before enabling delayed expansion so that change is not lost upon ENDLOCAL.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're echoing just the line delimiter, not the whole line:

echo %%l>>%tempfile%

I'm rusty on ms-dos scripts, so I can't give you more than that.